# Reset dependency to SNAPSHOT for development

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I upgraded to a new version of Maven (from 3.0.5 to 3.3.3) and noticed that the behaviour of `release:prepare` changed when there are SNAPSHOT dependencies in the pom.

A typical flow:

```
There are still some remaining snapshot dependencies.
: Do you want to resolve them now? (yes/no) no: : yes
Dependency type to resolve,: specify the selection number ( 0:All 1:Project Dependencies 2:Plugins 3:Reports 4:Extensions ): (0/1/2/3) 1: : 
Dependency 'com.example.project:module' is a snapshot (1.2.3-SNAPSHOT)
: Which release version should it be set to? 1.2.3: : 
What version should the dependency be reset to for development? 1.2.3: :
```

As you can see, it suggests to keep the dependency at the release version (1.2.3), instead of reset it to snapshot (1.2.4-SNAPSHOT) like older versions did. I most cases I would like the default to reset version back to SNAPSHOT.

Can I get the old behaviour back with configuration or similar?

Currently using version 2.5 of maven-release-plugin.

Comment: Maven 3.0 (was really bad and had many bugs at least you should have used 3.0.5)... to 3.3...Hm..Maven in version 3.3 does not exist...the version is [3.3.3](http://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)...BTW: Can you show pom files...Furthermore why not upgrade maven-release-plugin to the most recent one...

Comment: @khmarbaise I left out the patch number because I didn't think it was relevant, updated now.

Comment: You can't release project which contains SNAPSHOT dependencies...I assume you have not pinned the version of maven-release-plugin with the previous maven version...and that changed the behaviour...

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to change dependency to SNAPSHOT _after_ release. I know I can "pin" maven-release-plugin version but it feels odd to set it to an old version.